# add UIPanGestureRecognizer to a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have 2 UIViews; let's call'em mainView and otherView. mainView uses the whole screen (it is an iPad app) and otherView is a smaller one that appears on top of mainView. The problem is that I don't know how and where to add the UIPanGestureRecognizer. The code snippets I find shows the code, but its never clear (or I'm not sure why it never works).

Most of the time I get a "otherView may not respond to +addGestureRecognizer" warning, I've tried adding the UIGestureRecognixerDelegate in practically all headers file and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Hope you can help me out :)

Comment: if you could show some code on what you did, we will be able to help you with whats going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`addGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_57) is not a class method, it's an instance method. Other than that, without code there's not much I can say.

Also, check out CS193P Lecture 8: Gesture Recognizers. [iTunes Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/8-gesture-recognizers-october/id395605774?i=88370960)

Comment: Thanks for the link, those are great resources I wasn't aware of, It seems to work now ^o^